# Chilkat XML Lib : RemoveChild method

Tags: xml, chilkat

1) Using chilkat-9.5.0.79-x86-vc9 CkXml lib - RemoveChild (using a tag path) method to delete a record from the below xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<proxy>
<record>
<ip>103.108.126.247</ip>
<port>3128</port>
<time>71</time>
</record>
<record>
<ip>176.123.61.238</ip>
<port>3128</port>
<time>84</time>
</record>
<record>
<ip>51.79.140.76</ip>
<port>8080</port>
<time>91</time>
</record>
```

2) Code :

`xml.RemoveChild("proxy|record[1]");`

Result :
   No record deleted !

3) Code :

`xml.RemoveChild("proxy|record[1]|ip");`

Result :
   ip field of Record[1] is removed !

3) Question :
   Is this a bug ? or 
   What is the right way to use RemoveChild method to remove entire record[1] ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem internal to Chilkat and made the fix.  I'll post a pre-release v9.5.0.80 download here that fixes it.

32-bit: https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc9-1570.zip

64-bit: https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc9-1571.zip